# Invoke method in dynamically from groovy command line argument

Tags: groovy, command-line-interface, arguments

I need to be able to map the first string argument "groovy script.groovy firstArgument" to an method invokation.

script.groovy ==

```
def firstArgument() {
   println "test"
}

"$args"()
```

Does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Found out a solution.

    for (arg in this.args ) {
       "$arg"()
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def firstArgument() {
   println "test"
}

def methodName = args[0]
```

You can use [invokeMethod](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/MetaObjectProtocol.html#invokeMethod%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29):

```
invokeMethod(methodName, null)
```

Or [dynamic method invocation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+Groovy), thanks to @tim_yates:

```
"${methodName}"()
```